# How to set .htaccess for subdomain on godaddy linux host with one wordpress installed first at subdirectory?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My host root looks like:

```
/
.htaccess
index.php
  -wordpress1
    --wp-content
    --wp-include
    --.htaccess
    --index.php
    --...etc...
  -wordpress2
    --wp-content
    --wp-include
    --.htaccess
    --index.php
    --...etc...
```

I installed one wordpress first at subdirectory  **wordpress1** and use main domain point to it.

Now i want add a subdomain like **subdomain.domain.com**, subdomain is also a directory, point to subdirectory **wordpress2**, And i can visit it use **subdomain.domain.com**.

------ 1

my root .htaccess file like；

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And my root index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress1/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

------ 2

my **wordpress1** .htaccess file like；

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpess1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And my **wordpress1** index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

----- 3

my **wordpress2** .htaccess file like；

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpess2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And my **wordpress2** index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Now i can use **maindmain.com** to visit **wordpress1**, And i can't use **wordpress1.maindomain.com** to visit **wordpress2**, but can use  **maindomain.com/wordpress2** to visit.

How to change it?

Thanks!